# Oracle ASM Backup Strategy

Tags: oracle

When the Full Backup (hot backup)  happens and let us say it takes about 5-6 hours to complete.  Then what about the Transactions that happen during the backup.  Will it be recorded in the Backup file when the Full Backup is complete ?

Answer (score 2):

If you include [PLUS ARCHIVELOG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta007.htm#CHDCFGEI) in backup command, transactions that happened during the backup will be recorded in a separate file.